# How to fit a piecewise step function to be below my data points?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, piecewise

I have a custom function that takes 6 parameters. It creates a step "curve".
I want to optimize/fit the last 5 parameters (m1, m2, FL1, FL2 and FL3).

```
def steps(x, FL1, m1, FL2, m2, FL3):
    if x > m1:
        return FL1
    if x > m2:
        return FL2
    else:
        return FL3
```

I want to fit this function to always be *below* my data points.

Example:

[image: Simplified Example]

The real data looks slightly more complex, like this, but still not complex:

[image: Actual data]

What functionality can I use here to fit this function?

I assume `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` does not work due to `least_squares` is used. That way it will be centered around the data points.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit  

def steps(m, FL1, m1, FL2, m2, FL3):
    if m > m1:
        return FL1
    if mass > m2:
        return FL2
    else:
        return FL3

x_data = [8000, 7000, 6000, 5000]  
y_data = [300, 350, 400, 450]  

popt, _ = curve_fit(steps, x_data, y_data)
```

This fails:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

It does not seem to like the `if` statements in the function.

Comment: But have you tried scipy.optimize.curve_fit? Do you have any working example?

Comment: curve_fit does not work. It does not seem to like "if" expressions.

--> I have added the data to the main text.

Comment: Side note: How did you create these graphs which look like hand-drawn?

Comment: How do you know your `fit` graph is "below" the `Data` points when the step isn't aligned? You must be assuming some type of linear interpolation between the points.

Comment: @mkrieger1   ---> thats xkcd style in matplotlib.      https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html


Yes, a linear fit between these points can be assumed. The data points result from a optimization script. I can choose the interval/resolution of the data points to some degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your optimization only has 2 parameters to optimize; `m1`, `m2`. The height of the step follows from your interpolated data.  For example, `FL1 == y_data[0]` always.

You'll need to express this in your function, and you could use it in `curve_fit`. It also expects you to vectorize your function, but i just couldn't be bothered.

If we express this function

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

x_data = np.linspace(8000, 5000, 10)
y_data = np.array([400, 420, 440, 450, 453, 454, 452, 453, 453, 452])


def limit(m):
    return np.interp(m, np.flip(x_data), np.flip(y_data))


def constrained_steps(m, m1, m2):
    results = list()  # Could be vectorized if you cared enough.
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i] > m1:
            results.append(y_data[0])
        elif m[i] > m2:
            results.append(limit(m1))
        else:
            results.append(limit(m2))
    return np.array(results)


# Initialize initial guess at 2/3 and 1/3's through the x_data.
bounds = x_data[[-1,0]]
p0 = ((bounds[1]-bounds[0])*2/3 + bounds[0], (bounds[1]-bounds[0])*1/3 + bounds[0])
popt, _ = curve_fit(constrained_steps, x_data, y_data, p0=p0, bounds=bounds)
opt_m1, opt_m2 = popt

ms = np.linspace(bounds[0], bounds[1], 1000)
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.plot(ms, constrained_steps(ms, opt_m1, opt_m2))
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```